# How can I update related models in yii 2

Tags: yii2

I have 3 tables to manage my stock.

- `Items_table (item_id,label,stock...)` column `stock` has `0` default value.
- `orders_table (order_id,at_date,status)` column status has `0` default value.
- `orders_items_table(orderitem_id,order_id,item_id,quantity)` manage orders details.

what I want to do is to update order '`status`' `1` and update Items '`stock`' with `quantity` from `orders_items_table` by concerned `item_id`.

here is my `actionValidate`

```
public function actionValidate($id)
    {
         $model = $this->findModel($id);

         $query = new purchases::find()->where('purchase_id' = :id);
            echo $query->createCommand()->sql;


        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->purchase_id]);
        }

        return $this->render('validate', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you should end up with three models.

**Step 1:** create three `ActiveRecord` model I will create one for you only

```
class Order extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'orders';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id','status'], 'integer'],
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => Yii::t('app', 'Order Id'),
            'status' => Yii::t('app', 'Order Status'),
            'created_at' => Yii::t('app', 'Order Date'),
        ];
    }

    public function getOrderItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::className(), ['order_id' => 'id']);
    }

    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::className(), ['id' => 'item_id'])
            ->via('orderItems');
    }
}
```

Now you need to create OrderItem model, OrderItem hasOne Order and hasOne Item. After that create Item model that have many OrderItem and Orders.

**Step 2:** create your controller and the following

```
$order = Order::findOne($order_id);
if( ! is_null($order) ){
    //we found the order
    foreach ($order->orderItems as $orderItem) {
        //get the item
        $item = $orderItem->item;
        $item->stock = $item->stock - $orderItem->quantity;
        //save the item
        $item->save(); 
    }
    //update the order
    $order->status = 1;
    $order->save();
}
```

That code just to show you how to do the logic don't forget you need to do validation and data integrity.

see more [Active Record](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record)

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer solved your issue and you find it useful, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: use this with what ?

Comment: ok, but just any precision. suppose that I want not use actionValidate to update 'status', but directly with actionCreate, Update and Delete. How can I do that. NB: with Update it must soustract old_vlue and add new one. for example, I have 50 hp in stock, someone ordered 5 after he change to 10.

Comment: the same issue.

Comment: Thanks I will be back with a new issue.

Comment: You can call the action inside the same controller but its big design mistake, move all the logic to order model and just pass the id using the controller. So model will have function called whatEver($id), it will take id and all update delete and create action will use this method.